# JSON error "Can not instantiate abstract type" in a POST request to a Restful server

Tags: json, rest, http-post

I am trying to execute a POST request on a Restful Server, using JSON format (using Chrome's add-on Advanced Rest Api). Here's the JSON string:
(with headers: Accept: application/json; Authorization: Basic....)

```
{
"datecreated": 1355237359326,
"datemodified": 1355237359326,
"entrylocation": "Düdingen",
"entrydate": 1347351720000,
"entryduration": 11900,
"comment": "Random text",
"publicvisible": 2,
-
"coursetype": "Running track (Outdoor)",
"courselength": 600,
"numberofrounds": 12,
"track": "Fast track"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Can not instantiate abstract type [simple type, class ch.unifr.cybercoach.server.entities.jaxb.entries.Entry] (need to add/enable type         information?) 
at [Source: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput@65ab8182; line: 1, column: 2]
```

This is weird because the same POST request works with an XML format:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <entryrunning>
 <comment>Random text</comment>
 <entrydate>2012-09-11T10:22:00+02:00</entrydate>
 <entryduration>11900</entryduration>
 <entrylocation>Düdingen</entrylocation>
 <publicvisible>2</publicvisible>
 <courselength>600</courselength>
 <coursetype>Running track (Outdoor)</coursetype>
 <numberofrounds>12</numberofrounds>
 <track>
PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPGttbCB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5vcGVuZ2lzLm5ldC9rbWwvMi4yIj4KICA8RG9jdW1lbnQ+CiAgICAgICAgICA8L1BvbHlnb24+CiAgICAgICAgPC9QbGFjZW1hcms+CiAgICAgIDwvRm9sZGVyPgogICAgPC9Gb2xkZXI+CiAgPC9Eb2N1bWVudD4KPC9rbWw+Cg==</track>
 </entryrunning>
```

Anybody has some idea?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you're getting back a Java error message, which, as far as I know, chrome doesn't use. Is the error as a response from the api, or is chrome raising the error? If it's the api, it's probably a problem on their end.

Comment: It's a response from the api, I think. I was thinking that the only difference between the two formats is the <entryrunning> tag in the XML, which is the type of the entity - is there a way to indicate type in the JSON?

Comment: The data doesn't matter much if the api responds with an error. It means that it is making a mistake when parsing and processing your json data, and not while processing your xml data. These could be two completely different parts of their application, so the fact that the xml works, doesn't imply that there's anything wrong with your JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

sys.stderr turned out to be right - thank you (see comment below my question post). There was a problem on the server side with unmarshalling. Now that this is fixed, the following json string worked fine:

```
{"entryrunning" :{
"datecreated": 1355237359326,
"datemodified": 1355237359326,
"entrylocation": "Düdingen",
"entrydate": 1347351720000,
"entryduration": 11900,
"comment": "Random text",
"publicvisible": 2,
"coursetype": "Running track (Outdoor)",
"courselength": 600,
"numberofrounds": 12,
"track": "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPGttbCB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5vcGVuZ2lzLm5ldC9rbWwvMi4yIj4KICA8RG9jdW1lbnQ+CiAgICAgICAgICA8L1BvbHlnb24+CiAgICAgICAgPC9QbGFjZW1hcms+CiAgICAgIDwvRm9sZGVyPgogICAgPC9Gb2xkZXI+CiAgPC9Eb2N1bWVudD4KPC9rbWw+Cg=="
}}
```